# Jquery slide (animate) in / out based on selection

Tags: html, jquery, css, radio-button, jquery-animate

I have the following jsfiddle setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/f9JUj/13/

Basically when you select the radio for merc or bmw a engine size box slides in, when you click the radio button for audi the engine size box should disappear but at the moment only the background does and the box and text remains.

Secondly I may change the default radio that is checked on the page load ie, bmw or merc so in this case the engine size box should be visible, but when audi is selected this should disappear.

And the final question is I tried this code using Jquery 1.6.4, but did not work can anyone advise why this code might not work as I was thinking of using 1.6.4?

Thanks

Comment: The code in your jsFiddle is very simple and works the same for me in all versions of jQuery including 1.6.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `overflow: hidden`:

http://jsfiddle.net/f9JUj/14/

For your second question, just I'd just simulate a click action:

```
$("input[value='merc']").trigger("click");
```

Not sure about your final question